# Why I couldn't debug .cc file?

Tags: c++

why I added cerr debug points in .cc file, but it never print out when I run it, where could it possibly be manipulated and by what files?

Thanks!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org) and include the full error text.

Comment: You named it `Span`, not `span`. Also, it has _one_ template argument, not two.

Comment: c++ is case sensitive for any symbols you use.

Comment: You need to pick up a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @AnnW. `template<typename T, typename T>`...  T is being declared twice.  Make the second T another name, e.g. U. `template<typename T, typename U>` if you really need a second type.

Comment: Thanks, why I added cerr debug point in xxx.cc, but it never print out when I run the project? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519332/why-compile-into-old-so?noredirect=1#comment64456431_38519332

Comment: Don't change a question to something completely different after it has been answered!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your type is named `Span`, not `span`. Names are case-sensitive in C++. Secondly, your `Span` template takes two template arguments, while you provide only one. This works:

```
Span<int> ageSpan;
```